# Открытие обозревателя по нажатию на надпись

Tags: delphi

Как добавить в дельфи такую надпись, чтобы нажимая на неё у пользователя, открывался его браузер и в нем открывался сайт, который хочу я.

Answer (score 5):

Если я правильно понял, то как-то так:

```
procedure TForm1.Label1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
// для работы этой функции, нужно подключить в раздел Uses модуль ShellAPI
  If (ShellExecute(Application.MainForm.Handle, PChar('open'),
    PChar('http://... - нужный сайт'),
    Nil, Nil, SW_ShowNormal)<32) Then
      MessageBox(0,
        PChar('Не могу открыть браузер!'),
        PChar('Ошибочка вышла!'),
        MB_OK + MB_ICONERROR + MB_APPLMODAL + MB_TOPMOST);
end;

procedure TForm1.Label1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Font.Color:=clRed;
  Label1.Font.Style:=[fsUnderline];
end;

procedure TForm1.Label1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Font.Color:=clBlue;
  Label1.Font.Style:=[];
end;
```

Comment: В целом всё правильно, только я бы убрал все эти ужасные PChar.

    if (ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'http://... - нужный сайт', Nil, Nil, SW_ShowNormal)<32) then

      MessageBox(0, 'Не могу открыть браузер!', 'Ошибочка вышла!', MB_OK + MB_ICONERROR + MB_APPLMODAL + MB_TOPMOST);


так компактнее и понятнее имхо.

Comment: Не знал, что эти функции могут воспринимать обычные строки, поэтому всегда передавал им PChar.

Comment: @DelphiM0ZG, они не могут, но компилятор может автоматически привести тип **констатного выражения**. Кстати, в D2006 присутствовал баг из-за которого приходилось писать явно.